# Why can't I hide my input field where the type is a file type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to hide my input field of a file type, however despite having the hidden attribute it will not hide itself.

[image]
[image]

However, after I remove type="file", the code will hide itself properly

[image]
[image]

May I know if anyone knows if I can hide the file with type="file"? Thank you !

Comment: this is working for me : https://codepen.io/shubham-patil/pen/RwYNxXz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hidden` and `type="file"` are the same attribute. If you either define attribute `hidden`, you cannot use file upload, or define `type='file'`, you cannot make this element hidden. To solve the problem, you must use inline styling `display: 'none'` to hide this element and set the attribute `type="file"` without `hidden`.
First, declare ref for using with input element tag.

```
const uploadRef = useRef()
```

Then call the `uploadRef.current.click()` for show upload file window.

Code example

```
const FileUpload = () => {
  const uploadRef = useRef(null)
  
  const onSelectFile = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    if (!file) {
      console.log('No file selected')
      return
    }
    console.log(file)
    console.log(file.name)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={uploadRef} type='file' style={{display:'none'}} onChange={onSelectFile}/>
      <button type='button' onClick={()=>uploadRef.current.click()}>Upload File</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do this after i get back home.